# Create a column based on if a string is a substring in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, series

One of the columns in my data frames are identifier names with a specific naming convention. When it was entered, it wasn't entered correctly. I wanted to ask how I can find specific keywords to input in its own column in python. Maybe some sort of loop?

Example:

```
types = ['XYZ', 'OPQ', 'MNO', 'ABC']
```

current df:

```
ID  ID Name
45  I_name_ls_XYZ_random
46  I_22_name_ABC_random
47  I_name_ls_XYZ_random_45
48  I_name_ls_MNO_random
49  I_ls_OPQ_random_name
50  I_name_ls_ABC_random
51  I_name_ls_XYZ_random
52  I_name_MNO_random
```

Wanted result:

```
ID  ID Name                types
45  I_name_ls_XYZ_random    XYZ
46  I_22_name_ABC_random    ABC
47  I_name_ls_XYZ_random_45 XYZ
48  I_name_ls_MNO_random    MNO
49  I_ls_OPQ_random_name    OPQ
50  I_name_ls_ABC_random    ABC
51  I_name_ls_XYZ_random    XYZ
52  I_name_MNO_random       MNO
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **`str.extract`**

```
df['types'] = df.Name.str.extract('({})'.format('|'.join(types)))

   ID                     Name types
0  45     I_name_ls_XYZ_random   XYZ
1  46     I_22_name_ABC_random   ABC
2  47  I_name_ls_XYZ_random_45   XYZ
3  48     I_name_ls_MNO_random   MNO
4  49     I_ls_OPQ_random_name   OPQ
5  50     I_name_ls_ABC_random   ABC
6  51     I_name_ls_XYZ_random   XYZ
7  52        I_name_MNO_random   MNO
```

If you might want multiple matches you can use **`findall`**

```
df
   ID                     Name
0  45  I_name_ls_XYZ_ABCrandom

df.Name.str.findall(r'|'.join(types))
0    [XYZ, ABC]
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`pd.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) with a custom function / generator expression:

```
types = {'XYZ', 'OPQ', 'MNO', 'ABC'}

def string_filter(x):
    return next((i for i in x.split('_') if i in types), None)

df['types'] = df['ID_Name'].apply(string_filter)

print(df)

   ID                  ID_Name types
0  45     I_name_ls_XYZ_random   XYZ
1  46     I_22_name_ABC_random   ABC
2  47  I_name_ls_XYZ_random_45   XYZ
3  48     I_name_ls_MNO_random   MNO
4  49     I_ls_OPQ_random_name   OPQ
5  50     I_name_ls_ABC_random   ABC
6  51     I_name_ls_XYZ_random   XYZ
7  52        I_name_MNO_random   MNO
```